# the application stopped unexpectedly please try again?

Tags: android, android-activity

When I run below code, it's giving a message that:

```
 the application stopped unexcepctedlly pleas try again
```

Any one can help to deal with this problem.

```
public class TheNewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int counter;
    Button sub,add;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        display=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.dis);

     add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("your total is"+counter);
        }
    }); 
     sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("your total is"+counter);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here no  sub button Reference like this add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have not instantiated "sub" ....... and you are implementing its `onClickListner()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this before setting onClickListener:

```
sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.urbtnname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized Button `sub`. Add in your code:

```
sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); // if button2 is the id for sub in xml file.
```